# use array as datasource in paging library

Tags: android, kotlin, paging

i have arrayList of `HomeEntity`, can i able to use it on Paging Library?

```
// this is HomeDataSource class 
var dataSource: List<HomeEntity> =
     arrayListOf(
        HomeEntity(
            R.string.home_divide_title,
            R.string.home_divide_name,
            R.string.home_divide_story,
            R.drawable.ic_home_divide,
            R.color.common_red
        ),
        HomeEntity(
            R.string.home_report_title,
            R.string.home_report_name,
            R.string.home_report_story,
            R.drawable.ic_home_report,
            R.color.common_pink
        ))

// this is HomeEntity class
data class HomeEntity(
    var title: Int,
    var name: Int,
    var story: Int,
    var icon: Int,
    var iconColor: Int
)
```

i read some article on web, most of them use paging library with Retrofit or Room which provide data source(LiveData) automatically

my problem is i can't figure how to pass this array to paging library

Comment: What's the point of using the Paging library for this if you already have the whole list in memory anyway?

Comment: i read list from local file then create list of `HomeEntity` and finally show them

Comment: In which case I ask the exact same question as I asked above. The reason why Paging works with Room is because SQLite supports SKIP+TAKE (limit/offset), and has every other item on disk but not in memory

Comment: correct :) , thanks

Comment: Did you find any answer?